# Zend DB inserting relational data

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I'm using the Zend Framework database relationships for a couple of weeks now. My first impression is pretty good, but I do have a question related to inserting related data into multiple tables. For a little test application I've related two tables with each other by using a fuse table.

```
      +---------------+      +---------------+      +---------------+
      |     Pages     |      |     Fuse      |      |    Prints     |
      +---------------+      +---------------+      +---------------+
      | pageid        |      | fuseid        |      | printid       |
      | page_active   |      | fuse_page     |      | print_title   |
      | page_author   |      | fuse_print    |      | print_content |
      | page_created  |      | fuse_locale   |      | ...           |
      | ...           |      | ...           |      +---------------+
      +---------------+      +---------------+
```

*Above is an example of my DB architecture*

Now, my problem is how to insert related data to two separate tables and insert the two newly created ID's into the fuse table at the same time. If someone could could maybe explain or give me a topic related tutorial. I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you got separate models for each table. Then simply insert stuff in `Prints` table, store returned ID in variable. Then insert stuff in `Pages` table and store returned ID in another varialble. Eventually insert data in your `Fuse` table. You do not need any "at the same time" (atomic) operation here. ID of newly inserted rows are returned by `save()` (I assume you use autoincrement fields for this).

```
$printsModel = new Application_Model_Prints();
$pagesModel = new Application_Model_Pages();
$fuseModel = new Application_Model_Fuse();

$printData = array('print_title'=>'foo',
              ...);
$printId = $printsModel->insert( $printData );

$pagesData = array('page_author'=>'bar',
              ...);
$pageId = $pagesModel->insert($pagesData);

$fuseData = array('fuse_page' => $pageId,
                  'fuse_print' => $printId,
                  ...);
$fuseId = $fuseModel->insert($fuseData);
```

thus is pseudo code, so you may want to move inserts into your models and do somoe i.e. normalisation etc.

I also suggest paying more attention to fields naming convention. It usually helps and now you got `fuseid` but also `fuse_page`. So it either should be `fuse_id` or `fusepage` (not to mention I suspect this field stores id so it would be `fuse_page_id` or `fusepageid`).

Comment: Ive used shorten field names for the example. All namings in my database are perfect. Thanks for the tip, I will look into it.

Comment: This works perfectly. But is it the right way to do :P ?... if not, I will keep it like this and update it later in time

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly fine. You do not need any atomic operation here (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29) You just need to store some related data. and once you insert your page or print data, their ID are unaltered. So you can even create your fuse record next day - it still be fine as long as you remember your pageId and printId

Comment: Haha, I'm also trying the example below

Comment: I mainly meant "accept answer that helped", not "accept my answer". Many people asks but then do not "pay back" with points, which is annoying

Comment: I get it, but your answer helped an looks like a good example for other with the same question/problem.

Answer (score 0):

Prints and Pages are two entities . Create row clases for each

```
class Model_Page extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abastract 
{

public function addPrint($print)
{
  $fuseTb = new Table_Fuse();
  $fuse = $fuseTb->createRow();
  $fuse->fuse_page = $this->pageid;
  $fuse->fuse_print = $print->printid;
  $fuse->save();
  return $fuse;
}

}
```

Now when you create page

```
$page = $pageTb->createRow() ; //instance of Model_Page is returned
$page->addPrint($printTb->find(1)->current());
```

Comment: Something isnt right. It gived me an error because of the $fuse->save() Fatal error: Call to undefined method Module_Model_ModulePagesFuses::save()

Comment: this is pseudo code , your class name  will be different depending upon your autoloading namespace also you need to add $_rowClass = 'Model_Page' to your existing table class .

Comment: I've already done that. I didnt copy paste your code, but modified it to my application. But still gives me the save() error.

Comment: my bad forgot to create instance of fuse table class . now check

Comment: Ive used the example above. But will check this one aswell, Ill post the result in a minute :)

Comment: Cant get it to work fine. Been working on fixing it, but keeps giving the error Column 'fuse_page' cannot be null'